# Unknown field name error. Can't figure out SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm sure it's something small, but I can't figure out why this SQL statement isn't working.

```
INSERT INTO tempTable
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT * FROM [table] AS x RIGHT JOIN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT a.[Part number], Count(a.[Part number]) AS [Part Count] 
FROM  [table] AS a 
GROUP BY a.[Part number]
) 
AS y 
ON x.[Part number] = y.[Part number]
);
```

Every time I run the query in access, I get the error "The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'Part number'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.

When I take out the `INSERT INTO` wrapping and use just the select statement, it returns the results I want to insert into tempTable.

tempTable was created using this select statement, so I don't think it's an issue of mismatching column names.

Can anybody see an error with my statement?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you've got two columns with the same name, which isn't allowed for tables or views.  You should explicitly name the insert columns, and the select output columns.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but could it be that there are two fields in your recordset that are called `[Part Number]`. Perhaps instead of `SELECT *` you list the fields explicitly. Furthermore, your outer Select `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM [table] as x...)` (That first `SELECT * FROM`) is unnecessary.

Comment: Even if you don't think so, it does sound like `tempTable` doesn't have a field called `[Part number]`.  Even if `tempTable` was created from that `select` statement originally, it may have been given different column names explicitly in the `insert` statement.

Comment: Compare the field names from your *tempTable* with the field names returned by `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM [table] AS x RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT a.[Part number], Count(a.[Part number]) AS [Part Count] FROM  [table] AS a GROUP BY a.[Part number]) AS y ON x.[Part number] = y.[Part number])` They don't match up exactly.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. The query was returning two columns named [Part number], and since this isn't allowed, they were being named x_Part number and y_Part number. I fixed this and now it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you created the temp table by using the exact same select query in a Make Table query? Have you looked at tempTable in design view and confirmed the field names? Without seeing all of your fields, my guess is that your select statement outputs multiple fields with the same name.
Additionally, note that 'table' is a reserved word and should not be used as an object name, and the use of spaces in field names is considered poor practice. Just because you CAN do something, doesn't mean that you SHOULD.